# agrupar y combinar archivos con prefijos comunes

Tags: python, python-3.x, csv

Hice algunas funciones que me ayudan a descargar todos los currículos de las elecciones por precintos. Los nombres de los archivos descargados tienen el siguiente aspecto:

```
Hzwpukgh_2008Parliamentary-Majoritarian
Hzwpukgh_2008Parliamentary-PartyList
Hzwpukgh_2008Presidential
...
Truc_2008Presidential
```

Me da, para una elección dada y un precinto dado, lo siguiente :

```
"Election"," Map Level"," Precinct ID"," Precinct Name","Overall Results","#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili","#2 - Levan Gachechiladze","#3 - Shalva Natelashvili","#4 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili","#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze","#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili","#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia","Total Voter Turnout (#)","Total Voter Turnout (%)","Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)","Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)","Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
```

**Me gustaría reunir el currículum vítae de diferentes años de un precinto dado, digamos `Hzwpukgh`, a un currículum vítae que se parezca a este** :

```
                       2010 Presidential   2017 Presidential ...  
Tprolps Zhhrhzocpsp                67.68                 NaN
Levan Gachechiladze                20.96                 NaN
...
Npvynp Thynclshzocpsp                NaN               64.15
Davit Bakradze                       NaN               13.86
...
```

Pero, primer paso, estoy buscando fusionar los csvs en uno. Así que **cómo fusionar archivos con los mismos nombres antes del guión bajo?**

Parecería que..:

```
"Election"," Map Level"," Precinct ID"," Precinct Name","Overall Results","#1 - Mikheil Saakashvili","#2 - Levan Gachechiladze","#3 - Shalva Natelashvili","#4 - Arkadi (Badri) Patarkatsishvili","#5 - Davit Gamkrelidze","#6 - Giorgi (Gia) Maisashvili","#7 - Irina Sarishvili-Chanturia","Total Voter Turnout (#)","Total Voter Turnout (%)","Average votes per minute (08:00-12:00)","Average votes per minute (12:00-17:00)","Average votes per minute (17:00-20:00)"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Presidential","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
...
"2008 Parliamentary-Majoritarian","Precinct","1","39-1","Mikheil Saakashvili","74.48","18.45","1.74","5.92","3.71","0.58","0.12","862","58.24","1.19","1.45","1.05"
"2008 Parliamentary-Majoritarian","Precinct","10","39-10","Mikheil Saakashvili","61.62","24.75","3.03","5.56","5.05","0","0","198","75","0.25","0.34","0.2"
```

Entonces podría crear el dataframe mostrado arriba. Si tienes otros métodos, me encantaría escucharlos:)

## El mio intento

Intente el siguiente :

```
import glob
import random
import os
import pandas

def find_filesets(path="."):
    csv_files = {}
    for name in glob.glob("{}/*_*.csv".format(path)):
        # there's almost certainly a better way to do this
        key = os.path.splitext(os.path.basename(name))[0].split('-')[0]
        csv_files.setdefault(key, []).append(name)

    for key,filelist in csv_files.items(): 
        print(key, filelist)
        # do something with filelist
        create_merged_csv(key, filelist)

def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):
    with open('{}-aggregate.csv'.format(key), 'w+b') as outfile:
        for filename in filelist:
            df = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
            df.to_csv(outfile, index=False, header=None)

find_filesets('./Results')
```

Pero me devuelve :

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-64-3b33d1e84680> in <module>
      4 import pandas
      5 
----> 6 find_filesets('./Results')

<ipython-input-63-5f53b2750f85> in find_filesets(path)
      9         print(key, filelist)
     10         # do something with filelist
---> 11         create_merged_csv(key, filelist)
     12 
     13 def create_merged_csv(key, filelist):

<ipython-input-63-5f53b2750f85> in create_merged_csv(key, filelist)
     15         for filename in filelist:
     16             df = pandas.read_csv(filename, header=None)
---> 17             df.to_csv(outfile, index=False, header=None)

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in to_csv(self, path_or_buf, sep, na_rep, float_format, columns, header, index, index_label, mode, encoding, compression, quoting, quotechar, line_terminator, chunksize, tupleize_cols, date_format, doublequote, escapechar, decimal)
   3018                                  doublequote=doublequote,
   3019                                  escapechar=escapechar, decimal=decimal)
-> 3020         formatter.save()
   3021 
   3022         if path_or_buf is None:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in save(self)
    170                 self.writer = UnicodeWriter(f, **writer_kwargs)
    171 
--> 172             self._save()
    173 
    174         finally:

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save(self)
    286                 break
    287 
--> 288             self._save_chunk(start_i, end_i)
    289 
    290     def _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i):

C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\formats\csvs.py in _save_chunk(self, start_i, end_i)
    313 
    314         libwriters.write_csv_rows(self.data, ix, self.nlevels,
--> 315                                   self.cols, self.writer)

pandas/_libs/writers.pyx in pandas._libs.writers.write_csv_rows()

TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```